# How to start up rsyslog automatically?

Tags: services, upstart, rsyslog

Check current status of rsyslog

```
$ chkconfig --list rsyslog
rsyslog                   0:off  1:off  2:off  3:off  4:off  5:off  6:off
```

Start up rsyslog at some levels

```
$ sudo chkconfig --level 35 rsyslog on
```

It outputs these information:

```
insserv: warning: script 'plymouth-stop' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: Default-Start undefined, assuming empty start runlevel(s) for script `plymouth-stop'
insserv: Default-Stop  undefined, assuming empty stop  runlevel(s) for script `plymouth-stop'
The script you are attempting to invoke has been converted to an Upstart
job, but lsb-header is not supported for Upstart jobs.
insserv: warning: script 'failsafe-x' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: Default-Start undefined, assuming empty start runlevel(s) for script `failsafe-x'
insserv: Default-Stop  undefined, assuming empty stop  runlevel(s) for script `failsafe-x'
The script you are attempting to invoke has been converted to an Upstart
job, but lsb-header is not supported for Upstart jobs.
insserv: warning: script 'udevtrigger' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: Default-Start undefined, assuming empty start runlevel(s) for script `udevtrigger'
```

Check current status of rsyslog again

```
$ chkconfig --list rsyslog
rsyslog                   0:off  1:off  2:off  3:off  4:off  5:off  6:off
```

I am a novice. Please show me how to use rsyslog from beginning.

Answer (score 2):

As the output suggests the script was converted to an upstart job. So the best option right now is to open the file `/etc/init/rsyslog.conf`. You'll find a line `start on` there. Change this to

```
start on runlevel [35]
```

and save the file.

The command `initctl list` shows a list of of all init jobs and `initctl show-config rsyslog` will print out the status of rsyslog.